# Content is invisible

Tags: html, css

I am coding a website using onepage-scroll, and I'm encountering a very strange issue. In my last section (fourth), I added some content (notify me!), it displayed perfectly, and now I did something else (added scripts) and all the content disappeared.

Demo here: https://opencubes.github.io/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>OpenCubes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
  ...
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

  <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".main").onepage_scroll({
        sectionContainer: "section",
        ...
        direction: "vertical"
      });
      $('a.notify').on('click', function () {
        ...


      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <section class="first-page">
      <div class="description">
        <h1>The Minecraft Mod Marketplace</h1>
        <div>
          OpenCubes...
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="scroll-down">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i> Scroll Down
      </a>
    </section>
    <section class="second-page">
      <div class="description">
        <h1>Browse mods</h1>
        <div>
          With OpenCubes,...
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="images/browse.png" />
      <a href="#" class="scroll-down">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i> Keep scrolling...
      </a>
    </section>
    <section class="third-page">
      <div class="features">
        <div class="feature-spotlight sl-1">
          <div>
            <h2>Comment and vote</h2>
            ...
          </div>
          <img src="images/comments.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="feature-spotlight sl-2">
          <img src="images/files.png" />
          <div>
            <h2>Files and version manager</h2>
            In OpenCubes,...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="fourth-page">
      <div class="main">
        <h1>OpenCubes is still in development.</h1>
        <div class="send">
          <h2>Enter your email here to be notified when it's ready</h2>
          <input class="email" type="email"/>
          <a href="#">Notify me!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <!--[if !IE]><script>fixScale(document);</script><![endif]-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can see the content on Chrome. What content are you referring to?

Comment: @j08691 I am talking about the last section. I can see the backgroud, but the text and the input. In chrome AND in ff

Comment: What scripts have you added?

Comment: Downvote wasn't me, but I'm going to guess it's because you haven't exactly given a reduced test case here.  

That fourth section has `translate3d(0px, -200%, 0px);` set on it when it's supposed to be in view, which is why it's not visible.

Comment: @razvan.peter I aded firebase, jquery.cookie, and the a.notify event. Daniel Beck I'm to take a look.

Comment: @DanielBeck is right. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: @DanielBeck the problem is that I have two .main. Renamed the second (in the fourth-page) and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: On second look, I wasn't quite right -- that translate3d is set by your pagination script; it looks like you've put the classes `main onepage-wrapper` on that div, when the other faux-pages have class `features` instead  (`onepage-wrapper` appears to belong on the top-level div instead...)